# DateTime Type Gets Converted into bigint in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, datetime, uwp

I Am new to SQLite.I am trying to create  table from my model class in which I have DATETIME field.when sqlite table creatd from This Class The DATETIME column creted of type bigint.I know the reason because SQLite doesn't support DATETIME
So what should I do to create Column Of type TEXT in SQLITE without Chnging DATETIME type in my model Class. I found some post regarding to this but don't get satisfactory solution.please help.Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to store it different?  This is because of `storeDateTimeAsTicks = true`, the default. You'll need that when you ever want to query like `row.SomeDate < DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 1):

You can configure how `DateTime`s are stored in your connection string. Change the attribute `DateTimeFormat` to either "ISO8601" or "CurrentCulture".

**But:** I would *not* recommend to do that. If you ever want to sort by a datetime or you want to filter rows (give me all entries from the last 2 weeks) then the bigint approach is the most efficient one. While ISO8601 datetime strings are sortable, that is most likely not the case with localised CurrentCulture strings. So if you really want human-readable strings in your database then choose the ISO version.

Comment: sorry i didnt get it.in model class what datatype i need to give that filed instead DATETIME?